# VBScript Msgbox email from Outlook address book

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I currently have the following script:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
objMail.Display   'To display address book
```

This will open the Global Address list from Outlook.
Now when I single click or double click (doesn't matter) on a contact, I want a messagebox that contains the emailadress of the contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the selected contacts:

```
If .Display Then 
 'Recipients Resolved 
 'Access Recipients using oDialog.Recipients 
End If
```

For example:

```
Sub ShowContactsInDialog() 
 Dim oDialog As SelectNamesDialog 
 Dim oAL As AddressList 
 Dim oContacts As Folder 

 Set oDialog = Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog 
 Set oContacts = _ 
   Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts) 

 'Look for the address list that corresponds with the Contacts folder 
 For Each oAL In Application.Session.AddressLists 
  If oAL.GetContactsFolder = oContacts Then 
   Exit For 
  End If 
 Next 
 With oDialog 
  'Initialize the dialog box with the address list representing the Contacts folder 
  .InitialAddressList = oAL 
  .ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = True 
  If .Display Then 
   'Recipients Resolved 
   'Access Recipients using oDialog.Recipients 
  End If 
 End With 
End Sub
```